# Python socket connection: The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, sockets, client

I'm trying to connect to an external device. The device reports an IP address of ::ffff:a9fe:101%3. When I ping this address, I get a successful response. However I cannot connect to it in Python.

If I try to run this simple script:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
s.connect(('::ffff:a9fe:101%3', 9760, 0, 3))
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEMP\sample.py", line 3, in <module>
    s.connect(('::ffff:a9fe:101%3', 9760, 0, 3))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

In researching this issue, I have only seen this error occur when binding to an address. Why am I getting this error when attempting to connect to it?

Comment: `::ffff:a9fe:101%3` is not a valid IP address. Remove the `%3`.

Comment: As I understand it, the %3 represents the zone index in IPv6. I believe it's valid. Regardless, I get the same error after removing the %3.